# Unable to launch GenyMotion from eclipse in windows 10

Tags: android, eclipse, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm unable to launch GenyMotion from eclipse in windows 10. This is happening to me after the recent windows 10 update. The system runs into blue screen error(system service exception) and the system restarts. Please help.Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue, but I solved it. **SOLUTION is DISABLING HYPER-V.**

*Windows button -> type Turn Windows Features On/Off -> Uncheck “Hyper-V” -> Click OK -> Wait Until Things Done -> Click Restart*

Works like charm…

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too!

Comment: I am glad to hear, I had tough times struggling to solve it, and finally found a way...

Answer (score 0):

What version of Genymotion/VirtualBox are you using? More details will help. Also, have you tried running Genymotion from itself instead of the eclipse plugin?

Sounds to me the best solution here might simply to update the plugin, Genymotion, and VirtualBox. If all 3 are up to date, reinstalling them each might help.

Comment: GenyMotion Ver : 2.8.0
Oracle VM Virtual Box 5.0.26

Comment: Try updating Virtual Box. I believe 5.1.6 is the current latest.

Comment: updated  VB to 5.1.6. Still the machine is restarting. I tried opening GM separately and from within the eclipse. But still same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Well,to fix the System_Service_Exception error in Windows 10:

***Solution 1:***

**Try To Start The Computer In SafeMode**

Windows loads the least amount of drivers and services when it starts in safe mode. This prevents most blue screen errors from triggering, and gives the user a suitable environment to fix the problem, and copy important data.

**Upgrade Device Drivers To Fix The System_Service_Exception Error**

Most blue screen errors like the System_Service_Exception error occur due to driver issues. The driver might be corrupt or it might not be designed for Windows 10. While many older drivers will work with Windows 10, some do not.

You can upgrade drivers by going to your computer manufacturer’s website and looking for your computer. Once you find your computer’s model, download all the latest drivers and install them one-by-one. Restart the computer if prompted to do so. You can also use a third-party software like DriverDoc to find, download, and install drivers for you.

***Windows 10 System Recovery Options***

The Windows 10 system recovery options are used to reinstall Windows 10 without losing user data. The recovery options can be used to reset Windows from within Windows 10, and by using a bootable Windows 10 installation or recovery, DVD or USB as well.

1. Press the Windows Key > click Settings
2. Click Update & Security > Recovery > Click Get Started under Reset this PC.

There can be other reasons for this error I recommended to check below links:

[link1](https://www.xtremerain.com/how-to-fix-system-service-exception/)

[link2](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-system-service-exception-error-in-windows-10/)

Hope this helps!! If you have any doubts feel free to ask..